# MVC4 with Oracle error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm getting the following SqlClient.SqlException with my Oracle MVC4 web application.

**Cannot attach the file MvcAppContext.mdf as database.**

This makes no sense... a SqlException and it's Oracle.  Anybody know how to fix this?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.dotnetexamples.com/2013/05/cannot-attach-mdf-file-as-database.html

```
Run the following commands:

sqllocaldb.exe stop v11.0
sqllocaldb.exe delete v11.0
```

Now execute "update-database" command from package manager console and it will create database for you without any obstacles.